# SQL exclude negative quantity

Tags: sql, interbase

Please help, there is a request in which sometimes there is a negative value in the KOLVO_RZ column. Is it possible to check this in the request and if the value is negative, then return 0?

```
SELECT KOLVO_T - KOLVO_KKM - KOLVO_RZ AS KOLVO_T
FROM PRICE
```

Comment: Any reason why `CASE WHEN KOLVO_RZ < 0 THEN 0 ELSE KOLVO_RZ END AS KOLVO_RZ` wouldn't work?

Comment: Try `case when KOLVO_RZ < 0 then 0 else KOLVO_RZ end`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT KOLVO_T - KOLVO_KKM - (CASE WHEN KOLVO_RZ < 0 THEN 0 ELSE KOLVO_RZ END) AS KOLVO_T
FROM PRICE
```

Comment: Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 1, char 34.
WHEN

Comment: My bad. I missed the Interbase tag. I added parenthesis around the CASE statement after Googling. Try and see if that helps?

Comment: added, but the error is the same...

Comment: Which Interbase version?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample that works for me with InterBase 2020. Which InterBase version are you using?

```sql
create table hikers (
       hiker_id integer not null, 
       name varchar (256) not null,
       constraint pk_hid primary key (hiker_id));
create table hiker_data (
       hiker_id integer not null, 
       steps_gained integer,
       constraint fk_hid foreign key (hiker_id) references hikers (hiker_id));
commit;
insert into hikers values (1, 'Aarti');
insert into hikers values (2, 'Bala');
insert into hikers values (3, 'Chaaya');
insert into hikers values (4, 'Deepak');
insert into hiker_data values (1, 20);
insert into hiker_data values (1, 10);
insert into hiker_data values (1, -5);
insert into hiker_data values (1, 15);
insert into hiker_data values (1, -20);
insert into hiker_data values (2, 12);
insert into hiker_data values (2, 6);
insert into hiker_data values (2, 20);
insert into hiker_data values (2, -5);
insert into hiker_data values (2, 10);
insert into hiker_data values (2, -18);
insert into hiker_data values (3, 20);
insert into hiker_data values (3, 10);
insert into hiker_data values (3, -5);
insert into hiker_data values (3, 15);
insert into hiker_data values (3, -20);
insert into hiker_data values (3, 12);
insert into hiker_data values (4, 6);
insert into hiker_data values (4, 20);
insert into hiker_data values (4, -5);
insert into hiker_data values (4, 10);
insert into hiker_data values (4, -18);
commit;
/* test foreign key enforcement */
insert into hiker_data values (-100, -18);
```

and then, I execute the following queries successfully.

```sql
select hiker_id, 
       SUM(0 + (CASE WHEN steps_gained < 0 THEN 0 
                     ELSE steps_gained 
                     END)) AS total_steps_climbed,
       SUM(0 + (CASE WHEN steps_gained > 0 THEN 0 
                     ELSE steps_gained 
                     END)) AS total_steps_descended,
       SUM(steps_gained) AS final_tally
  from hiker_data
group by hiker_id;

select hiker_id, 
       (CASE WHEN steps_gained < 0 THEN 0 
                     ELSE steps_gained 
                     END) AS steps_climbed
  from hiker_data
 where hiker_id=2;
```